# What's the soonest I can send a signal to a background process (trap)?

Tags: bash, shell, signal

I have a script from which I run a second script in a subshell. What's the soonest that can send a signal to the second script?

script1:

```
./script2 &
kill -SIGCONT $!
```

script2:

```
echo "~~ ENTRY"

trap 'SUSPEND=false' SIGCONT

SUSPEND=true
while $SUSPEND; do; sleep 1; done

echo "~~ EXIT"
```

This won't work, the terminal will just hang there in "suspended" mode. My guess is that because I call `kill` straight away after I run script2, the trap in script2 doesn't have time to get parsed, and thus nothing happens - race condition.

So what's the soonest I can send the signal to the child process - making sure that it gets trapped?

Comment: There's no way to predict. Theoretically, if the system is busy enough with high-priority processes, `script2` might NEVER get to the `trap` command.

Comment: What you could do is have `script2` do something like write into a file after it traps the signal. `script1` could loop, checking for a modification of the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a message to a named pipe as a signal that `script2` is ready to handle the signal.

script1:

```
mkfifo /tmp/pipe
./script2 &
read nothing < /tmp/pipe
kill -CONT $!
```

script2:

```
echo "~~ ENTRY"

trap 'SUSPEND=false' SIGCONT
echo ready > /tmp/pipe

SUSPEND=true
while $SUSPEND; do; sleep 1; done

echo "~~ EXIT"
```